# Making a resistive load using Resistor

Tags: load

I am trying to make a load using resistor that can bear 12V 4A rated values.
I have calculated a resistance but that has a low resistance and high power rated resistor i.e. 3 ohms 48 Watt resistor. It is impossible to find this so please help me regarding the load resistance.
Thankyou

Comment: 12 volts at 5 amps is 2.4 ohms.

Comment: Sorry!! i calculated it for 10A rating..  Andy aka

Comment: I've got some nichrome resistance wire from a toaster in my junk pile...

Answer (score 1):

A resistor network will distribute the power dissipation across multiple resistors. Using three 10ohm 25W resistors in parallel will result in a 3.3ohm 75W resistance.

Answer (score 0):

> It is impossible to find this

There are plenty to choose from such as this from [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/resistors-fixed-value/panel-chassis-mount-resistors?resistance=3ohm): -

[image]

Comment: tell me if you have to design a load for 12V and  10 amp  rating. So what values would you prefer?

Comment: Thankyou :) But i am waiting for the ans of my last ques :)

Comment: I think you should look on Farnell (as per the link in my answer) and select the appropriate value resistor and do a farnell search.